# Owncloud - wrong url on activation links

Tags: php, owncloud

I have problem with Owncloud. After creating a new user, email sended to that user was with private IP address, not with domain name. Example verification link:

`http://192.168.3.103:4490/index.php/index.php/settings/users/setpassword/form/728851077702434409735/some.username`

I would like to repair that. It need to be in format

`https://cloud.mydomain.pl:4490/index.php/index.php/settings/users/setpassword/form/728851077702434409735/some.username`

Owncloud config below

```
$CONFIG = array (
  'instanceid' => 'xxx',
  'passwordsalt' => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxx',
  'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    1 => 'mydomain',
    2 => 'cloud',
    3 => 'https://cloud.mydomain.pl:44900',
    4 => '192.168.3.103:4490',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/html/data',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'https://cloud.mydomain.pl:44900',
  'overwritecondaddr' => '^192\\.168\\.3\\.103$',
  'dbtype' => 'sqlite3',
  'version' => '10.6.0.0',
  'logtimezone' => 'UTC',
  'installed' => true,
  'loglevel' => 0,

  // LOGGING
  // "log_type" => "owncloud",
  // "logfile" => "owncloud.log",
  // "loglevel" => "0",
  // "logdateformat" => "F d, Y H:i:s",
  // "mail_smtpdebug" => true;

  'maintenance' => false,
  'theme' => '',
  'mail_domain' => 'mydomain.pl',
  'mail_from_address' => 'admin',
  'mail_smtpmode' => 'smtp',
  'mail_smtpsecure' => 'ssl',
  'mail_smtpauth' => 1,
  'mail_smtpauthtype' => 'LOGIN',
  'mail_smtphost' => 'mydomain.pl',
  'mail_smtpport' => '465',
  'mail_smtpname' => 'admin@mydomain.pl',
  'mail_smtppassword' => 'xxx',
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after `'overwrite.cli.url'` add:

```
'overwritehost' => 'cloud.mydomain.pl',
```